# How can i get Azure ResourceGroup costs using az cmdlets in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get resourcegroup costs by the following

```
  # all details
 Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup "demo-rg" -StartDate 2021-12-01 - 
 EndDate 2022-01-27 |  Select-Object *

#or some details 

Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup "demo-rg" -StartDate 2022-01-01 - 
EndDate 2022-01-27 | Select-Object InstanceName, Currency, PretaxCost | Sort- 
Object -Property PretaxCost -Descending
```

But is there an equivalent command in the az cmds , as the arm will be phased out by Microsoft ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, **`AzureRM`**  module will be deprecated on 29 February 2024 not **`Az`** module.

The command `Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail` belongs to **`Az`** module and still can be used to fetch the details of resource group costs.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

```
 Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup "RGName"
```

[image]

To fetch the consumption usage details for **subscription scope**, you can also make use of below query:

```
az consumption usage list --subscription  "SubscriptionID" --start-date  "2022-02-01"  --end-date  "2022-02-02"
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail (AzureRM.Consumption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.consumption/get-azurermconsumptionusagedetail?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Comment: ok i have tried that and get az : Command group 'consumption' is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release. It then goes and gets my data. But how can we interpret the data in terms of getting costs in a dollar value ?

Comment: Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail doesnt bring back anything. It runs , completes but nothing is displayed on the screen

Comment: Can you please include the snips on what are you exactly trying?

Comment: I try the command az consumption usage list --subscription  "SubscriptionID" --start-date  "2022-02-01"  --end-date  "2022-02-02" and it gives results which will be fine for now. However Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail doesnt do anything. So with the first command az consumption , how can i extract how much each resource is costing ?

Comment: az consumption usage list gives you all the cost details of each resource in subscription scope

Comment: Yes , but is the pretax value in my example would be for the day i assume ? so i should make it az consumption usage list --subscription "SubscriptionID" --start-date "2022-02-01" --end-date "2022-02-28" to get the month ?

Comment: The output is quite detail and not really helpful. Is there a way to get it in tabular form or order by cost ascending or descending ?

Comment: Can you provide what details you need in output?

Comment: the details i am after from the output for the specified date range is the cost of the resource. So if i filter for 1month then how much is that resource costing for the month . I would like to output this in ascending order of cost . If the pretaxcost is for example 0.000057638218... what does that mean in terms of dollars for the cost of the resource for that month. Do i need to do some calculation like multiply by quantity etc ?